# Does calling .click(); always call all event handlers before returning?

Tags: jquery, event-handling

If I have the following code:

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    console.log("2");
});

console.log(1);
$("#button").click();
console.log(3);
```

Can I rely on the output to always be the following?

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: I believe so yes, as the methods you have used in your code example are synchronous. However, this may change if the content of your event handlers uses async logic, such as animations and AJAX requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your click event handler doing sync tasks - YES

if you have in click event handler some async things - NO

Answer (score 1):

In your example, yes as those are synchronous tasks. Unless you have asynchronous code being handled.